# Is it a best practice to give all admins the system administrator profile?

Tags: profile, bestpractice, admin

A team reporting up to me that uses Salesforce is experiencing severe disagreements around whether admins should all be given the system administrator profile, or if all but the lead admin should be given more restricted profiles, in accordance with the principle of least privilege.

- No end users are assigned the sys admin profile, it is only given to certified admins (of varying levels of experience, but mostly around a year of experience).
- And this team already has a review process where each admin has their own sandbox, and the lead admin reviews all change sets during deployment into production.

However, our lead now feels that the other admins should have a more restrictive profile for security purposes. I am getting conflicting answers on whether this is actually considered a best practice or even reasonable.

I understand that devs should be given more restricted profiles, but I can't find any best practices or recommendations for admins specifically.

Unfortunately I know very little about Salesforce, but I'm being called in to help mediate this disagreement.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with "principle of least privilege". However, you need redundancy - at least two admins or some way another user can gain full permissions if the primary admin becomes unavailable.

Comment: what would a more restricted profile be?  No `Modify All Data`, no `User Management` ??

Comment: What important reasons are stated by those who argue for a larger number of sys admins?